# Problemas al recibir archivos y datos por formData en PHP desde axios and vue

Tags: php, json, vue.js, axios, multipart

Estoy tratando de enviar archivos y datos por formData desde Vue usando axios por el metodo post, ya que debo enviar el archivo y los datos en la misma petición, pero al momento de capturarlos en mi Código PHP, no puedo leer los datos, pero el archivo si lo puedo leer perfectamente.

Comparto mi template de Vue

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" v-model="pqr.documento" id="pqr_documento"
            placeholder="N° de documento"/> 
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" @change="onFileChange" multiple/>
```

Comparto mi código JS en Vue

```
data() {
 return {
  selectedFiles: [],
  sizeSelectedFiles: 0,
  pqr: {
   documento: "",
  }
 }
},

methods: {
 enviarPQR: async function() {
  this.showProgress = true;
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", this.selectedFile);
  formData.append("pqr_documento", this.pqr.documento);

  for (var i = 0; i < this.sizeSelectedFiles; i++) {
    formData.append("file[]", this.selectedFiles[i]);
  }

  let vue = this;
  await this.axios.post("pqr.php?dato=insertarpqrweb", formData,
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log("RESPONSE API: " + response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.$utilidad.printConsole(error);
  })
  .then(function() {
    vue.showProgress = false;
  });
 },

 onFileChange(event) {
   this.sizeSelectedFiles = event.target.files.length;
   this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
 }
}
```

Comparto mi código PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
Authorization, X-Requested-With");

$_POST = file_get_contents("php://input");
$documento = $_POST['pqr_documento'];
echo 'RESP DATA:  ' . $documento;

 foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $val) {
     $nombre = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
     print_r('RESP FILE: ' . $nombre);
 }
```

Salida por consola:

```
RESPONSE API: 
RESP DATA:
RESP FILE: archivo.pdf
```

Evidentemente desde PHP pude recibir el nombre del archivo pero no he podido recibir los datos que encapsulé en el FormData desde vuejs

Comment: Intenta poner dos `var_dump($_POST);` uno antes y otro después de esta línea: `$_POST = file_get_contents("php://input");` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: a simple vista se ve que solo llenas formData con this.pqr.documento pero en ese momento que datos tiene this.pqr.documento??? valida que no sea undefinid o null

Comment: Usando los dos var_dump($_POST); obtengo lo siguiente:
RESPONSE API: array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  string(9) "undefined"
}
string(0) ""
RESP DATA:  
RESP FILE: archivo.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` se obtiene automaticamente sin necesidad de leer `php://input`. Bastaria comentar/remover la primera linea.

```
// $_POST = file_get_contents("php://input");
$documento = $_POST['pqr_documento'];
echo 'RESP DATA:  ' . $documento;
```

Normalmente `file_get_contents("php://input")` se usa para obtener datos en bruto de la peticion POST (*request body*) cuando se envia tal cual, por ejemplo, un JSON  por lo que retornara un `string` con el cuerpo de la peticion completa (en este caso codificada como `multipart/form-data`, que tu tendrias que decodificar).